# HandleChange in Javascript with React and Semantic Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

```
const languageOptions = [
    { key: '0', text: 'English', value: 'english' },
    { key: '1', text: 'Portuguese', value: 'portuguese' },
]

handleChange = field => (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({[field]:value})
}
      //what is difference between this functions?
handleChange = field => event => {
   this.setState({[field]:event.target.value})
}

<Input onChange={this.handleChange('language')} options={languageOptions} value={this.state.language} />
```

I do not understand why that second handleChange doesn't work, can anyone explain? I usually use the second way (with the `handleChange ('location')`), but it does not work ... What does `(e, {value})` mean?

Answer (score 1):

`handleChange = (e, { value })` can also be written as `handleChange = (e, valueObject)` where valueObject is `{value: 'YOUR_VALUE_HERE'}`.

This is called object deconstructing and you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

In order to get your code working the way that you want it to you will have to modify your `handleChange` function to be the following:

```
handleChange = field => (event, { value }) => {
   this.setState({[field]: value})
}
```

Comment: `handleChange = (e, { value })` don't would be `const {value} = e`?? I try do this, but doesn't work... `handleChange = (e){ const {value} = e   console.log(value) //undefined }`

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are asking here. Your original question was "What does (e, {value}) mean?". Are you now asking what the `Input` property types are?

Comment: I wan't to know what is `(e, {value})`... Because it isn't const {value} = e

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i do not understand why `e` was passed and don't was used

Comment: I've reformulated the question to make it clearer, I still do not understand the difference between these two functions ... when I use `<input onChange = {this.handleChange ('anyValue')} />`, using `handleChange = field = > event => {}` works normally, but with `<Input />` (from Semantic Ui), the `handleChange` does not work

Answer (score 1):

Really good question! Let me try to explain.

In your first function

```
handleChange = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({same:value})
}
```

your function is accepting `e` and `{value}` as function parameter. however your second function is

> concise body syntax, where in the "return" is function body. So every expression after => is a function. This is the typical example of `Currying`

let me explain it by example

```
handleChange = field => event => {
   this.setState({[field]:event.target.value})
}
```

Above function after Babel compilation becomes

```
const handleChange = function(field) {
  return ( function(event) {
     return 'something'
   })
}
```

The second approach creates a `closure` + `currying` type of function. You can keep adding `=>` and it will keep returning function. If you try to check the compiled code you could see something similar as above.

Hence In the first function

`handleChange = (e, { value })`

`setState` works fine because the `e` and `{value}` are the function parameters and has no closure, however in second

`handleChange = field => event =>`

`event` is the parameter of inner function in a closure. To read more about it you can go here [Currying in JavaScript ES6](https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400)

Hope this helps!

Comment: why i pass `e` in parameter and i don't use it? `(e//?, { value })`

Comment: `e` represent event object returned by the DOM. if you don't need that one you should not use.

Comment: if i don't pass `e` in parameter, `value` will be `undefined`... if i pass just `e`, and in function i do `const {value} = e`, `value` will be undefined too